# Lambda and Generics: Why Does This Compile?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

This is a shortened sample of my code to prove my point:

```
public class Tmp {

  static class X {
    void setStr(String blah) {
    }
    String getStr() {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public void test() {
    createCheck(X::getStr, "");   // supposed to compile
    createCheck(X::getStr, 123);  // rather not: int isn't String
  }

  private <T, V> BiPredicate<T, String> createCheck(Function<T, V> func, V value) {
    return new BiPredicate<T, String>() {

      @Override
      public boolean test(T t, String ref) {
        assertThat(func.apply(t))
            .as(ref)
            .isEqualTo(value);
        return true;
      }

    };
  }

}
```

IMHO, the compiler should see that `V` in `createCheck()` should be `String` coming from the getter-function, which is why it should complain about the int. Or the other way around.

So why does this compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your signature is:

```
private <T, V> BiPredicate<T, String> createCheck(Function<T, V> func, V value) {
```

You have no bounds on `T` or `V` so absolutely any values of `T` or `V` would compile.

You *return* a `BiPredicate<T, String>` however, so the `isEqualTo` method takes the `String ref` and compares its equality to the `Object value` - this is also perfectly legal as I suppose `isEqualTo` takes an `Object` to mimic the behaviour of `Object.equals`.

---

In your example:

```
createCheck(X::getStr, 123);
```

`V` is simply `Object` as that is the tightest type bound that can apply to `String` and `Integer`.

---

Did you perhaps mean:

```
private <T> BiPredicate<T, String> createCheck(Function<T, String> func, String value) {
```

Comment: Well, "mean", yes. But, then I'd have to code a method per type I want to pass as `value`. And that's not what I meant to do...

Comment: I can see what you are trying to do @sjngm, but I can't see a way to do it safely. You could try `<T, V> BiPredicate<T, V> createCheck(Function<T, V> func, V value)` - but that obviously has a different return to your original method. This would result in a `BiPredicate<X, Object>` in the second case; it may cause the compile errors you are looking for...

Comment: Nope, `BiPredicate<T, V>` affects the parameters to `test()`.

Comment: Exactly - currently you have some value of type `V` and some mapper that maps that value from a type `T` to a type `V`. You then have a `BiPredicate` takes a `V`, turns it into a `T` and then compares it to an arbitrary `String`. That doesn't make a huge amount of sense...